# Ajax post to php > get php variable with xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

> I want to update my table with javascript every couple seconds.

So far I made an ajax post request to my **update.php** and trigger if is set. Then do a **mysql query** and put the **resultset** in a **json variable**.

After this i get it with a **XMLHttpRequest**.

> The problem is that every **XMLHttpRequest** example uses echo json. But
>   when I put my echo json in my isset post check it wont return anything
>   anymore.

*I think the problem is that it can't **echo**?*

**This is my code:**

**PHP**:

```
if (isset($_POST["updateTable"])) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

        $rsArray[] = array();
        while ($row) {
            $rsArray[] = $row;
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        }
        echo json_encode($rsArray);
    }
```

**AJAX**:

```
var updateTable = "true";
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../EXT_PHP/update.php', 
            data: { updateTable: updateTable }
        });
        console.log(updateTable);
    }, 3000);
```

**xmlhttpRequest**:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    oReq.onload = function() {
        alert(this.responseText);
    };
    oReq.open("get", "../EXT_PHP/update.php", true);
    oReq.send();

}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you Tried to set the header of you PHP Script to JSON?

header('Content-Type: application/json');

Note that the header must be set before the first output of your Programm (i.E. the first echo)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if (isset($_POST["updateTable"])) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

        $rsArray[] = array();
        while ($row) {
            $rsArray[] = $row;
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        }
        echo json_encode($rsArray);
    }
```

if that doenst work still you should check if there has been any errors within the json_encode function, there are some problems with encoding by time. Use

```
echo json_last_error_msg();
```

for this.